# Jfrog Pipelines not syncing when I changed values.yaml

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

I have updated values.yaml but not pipelines.yaml and that update was not synced.

To get the changes effective, I had to manually sync the pipeline - is there a solution to this? How can I automatically sync the pipeline on values yaml file changes as well?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to move to config folder structure which means create a folder called `.jfrog-pipelines` and place your values.yaml and pipelines.yaml files under this folder.

Check the sample example here in [JFrog Public Repository](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-pipelines-simple-example)